# Accessing the HttpContext in Application Service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, httpcontext, abp

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate (ASP.NET Core) to create a CRM for the leads to go into.

These leads are pushed into the system via the API (Application Service layer, not the dynamic API).

I had planned on running a quick lookup on the lead source using request URL (from `HttpContext`) as its a required field in my model.

My question is: What's the best way to get the request URL (origin) of the post request in Application Service layer?

An example is as follows:

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: Core, just realised that the example I gave was a model , however just to clarify I'm trying this in the application layer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inject and use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```cs
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    protected HttpContext HttpContext => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AboutModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
    }
}
```